# Trying to implement Registration in Rails, but execution expires when form submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer

This is the error I see:

```
Timeout::Error in Devise/registrationsController#create

execution expired
```

This is what my development.rb looks like:

```
 MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/environment.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin


  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' } #Make sure to set 'host' to domain name in production.  
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
     config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
     config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
     config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

end
```

I check my logs, this is what I see, once I click the 'Submit' button on the Registration form:

```
Started GET "/users/register" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-02-11 19:19:23 -0500
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
nil
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (2.4ms)
Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (98.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 160ms (Views: 109.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-02-11 19:20:03 -0500
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qWs4IOH3L+GT/Sld8rZRlhXi8JM0pe0NtWG4Tn9XRIU=", "user"=>{"username"=>"marcamillion", "f_name"=>"marc", "l_name"=>"gayle", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"marc@amillion.com"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
nil
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: f_name, l_name
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('marc@amillion.com')) LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('marcamillion')) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('marc@amillion.com')) LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."confirmation_token" = 'DCo8QgqWQfnYWq20n5Uf') LIMIT 1
  AREL (31.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "password_salt", "reset_password_token", "remember_token", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "username", "f_name", "l_name", "created_at", "updated_at", "invitation_token", "invitation_sent_at", "plan_id", "current_state", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "confirmation_sent_at") VALUES ('marc@amillion.com', '$2a$10$55hQTGZpUKbeT5n30/eyau96jf5zzd18t19jV/Y4g8Urou/El4vKy', '$2a$10$55hQTGZpUKbeT5n30/eyau', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'marcamillion', NULL, NULL, '2011-02-12 00:20:03.699983', '2011-02-12 00:20:03.699983', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DCo8QgqWQfnYWq20n5Uf', NULL, '2011-02-12 00:20:03.699855')
Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.0ms)

Sent mail to marc@amillion.com (30009ms)
Date: Fri, 11 Feb 2011 19:20:03 -0500
From: no-reply@myapp.com
To: marc@amillion.com
Message-ID: <4d55d233bfe9f_bd4880443b3c837ee@MyMacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome marc@amillion.com!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=DCo8QgqWQfnYWq20n5Uf">Confirm my account</a></p>
Completed   in 30349ms

Timeout::Error (execution expired):
```

Comment: do you have SMTP server running on localhost?

Comment: hrmm....I never explicitly set it up. But, as far as I am concerned, I thought the only thing I had to have was the above set in my development.rb file. How do I check if the SMTP server is running ?

Comment: I doubt you have one running unless you manually installed and/or started it locally.  I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you don't have an SMTP server running locally.  Unless you really need the mail to be delivered in development, then you can remove this stuff and it should not error on you:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' } #Make sure to set 'host' to domain name in production.  
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```

If you do want mail delivered in dev, then google setting up smtp server.  Or you can even use something like gmail as an SMTP server

Comment: on closer inspection, perform deliveries is set to false, so I would expect it not to try to connect to smtp... I would still try removing the config and see what happens.

Comment: This works nicely. I just commented it out and no more timing out. Thanks.